# How to use \clist_map_tokens:Nn?

Tags: expl3, comma-separated-list

[p. 175](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf): `\clist_map_tokens:Nn⟨clist var⟩{⟨code⟩}` calls `⟨code⟩{⟨item⟩}` for every `⟨item⟩`stored in the `⟨comma list⟩`. If the `⟨code⟩`consists of a single function this is equivalent to `\clist_map_function:nN`. Could someone please show an example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

%\clist_map_tokens:nn {x,y,x} {(#1)} % ERROR
\clist_map_inline:nn {x,y,x} {(#1)}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `\clist_map_inline:Nn` or `\clist_map_inline:nn` you can only use `#1` in the second argument, to refer to the current item in the loop.

With `\clist_map_tokens:Nn`, the second argument should be a function with *one fewer argument* passed than those it takes; the trailing one will be supplied as the braced current item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\makematrix}{O{0pt}m}
 {
  \begin{bmatrix}
  \clist_map_tokens:nn { #2 } { \erwann_make_row:nn { #1 } }
  \\[\dim_eval:n { -\normalbaselineskip - #1 }]
  \end{bmatrix}
 }
\cs_new:Nn \erwann_make_row:nn { \clist_use:nn { #2 } { & } \\[#1] }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\makematrix{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}\ne\makematrix[12pt]{{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another advantage to `\clist_map_inline:nn` is that `\clist_map_tokens:nn` is fully expandable, but notice the hollow star.

Comment: One gets the same result with `\clist_map_inline:nn { #2 } { \erwann_make_row:nn { #1 }{##1} }`, so I take it the value added is your last comment.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike for `\clist_map_inline:nn` the second argument to the `_map_token:nn` functions (the same is true for e.g. `\prop_map_tokens:Nn` etc.) is not a definition for an internal macro, instead it should be called with some tokens in the second argument which expect a following brace group containing the list item. For instance, the following just outputs every item:

```
\clist_map_tokens:nn { a, b, c } { \use:n }
```

This is useful if your code needs another argument which just gets forwarded. For instance, what if we want to output only the numeric items in a clist which are bigger than another given number? You could achieve this fully expandable with the following function (that you could then nest in the argument of another clist function with an `e`-type expansion):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \mymodule_filter_numbers:nn #1#2
  {
    \clist_if_empty:nF {#2}
      {
        \exp_args:Ne \exp_not:o
          {
            \exp_not:N \use_none:n
            \clist_map_tokens:nn {#2} { \__mymodule_filter_numbers:nn {#1} }
          }
      }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__mymodule_filter_numbers:nn #1#2
  {
    \int_compare:nT { (#2) #1 } { , { \exp_not:n {#2} } }
  }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \filternumbers { m m }
  {
    \mymodule_filter_numbers:nn {#1} {#2}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\edef\foo{\filternumbers{>5}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}}\show\foo

\begin{document}
\filternumbers{>5}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the value added with respect to `\clist_map_function:nN`, then?

Comment: @Erwann ... (You don't look for problems to use tools for, you look for tools to solve problems you have.)

Comment: @Erwann what if the function needs to get some status information or some other kind of second argument that should be forwarded?

Comment: The advantage boils down to expand-ability, thanks.

Comment: @Erwann indeed, but for people obsessed with expandably doing what can be done expandably this is an important difference :) (I'm one of those people, see my packages `etl` and `expkv`)